# Built an answer to my own question based on two other answers. Share or keep to myself?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question and swiftly received two excellent answers. Based on those, I built my own function that is exactly what I was looking for, and that also takes into account another aspect of the question briefly mentioned in a parenthesis.

Now I'd like to share that function even though it is a very basic Python thing that the majority of this site would be more that able to write on their own. Anyway, I was thinking to add it as an edit in the question, but I'm concerned other users would find the question to be bloated since it's pretty lengthy in the first place. Therefore, I've also considered to add my suggestion as a separate answer, but I'm concerned that that would be considered disrespectful to the original answers, and also that it would be considered as a form of fishing for votes. Also, if the question already has received working solutions, why bother at all?

**tl;dr**

1. Posted a question
2. Got two excellent suggestions
3. Built my own solution with some minor tweaks based on those suggestions
4. Would like to share that solution.

**My options are:**

1. Forget it
2. Add my suggestion as an edit in the question itself
3. Post it as a separate answer

**What do you suggest?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have built up an answer to your question, then it's an answer, so answer your own question.

You can always state in this answer that you put it here for future reference or that you think it might help others.

If you're concerned about vote fishing, you don't have to put your answer as accepted, and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: and if you're really concerned about vote fishing mark your answer as Community Wiki.

Comment: I'm sure everyone already knows this and thought it was too obvious to mention, but...you must provide [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) to the others whose answers you've drawn upon.

Comment: `You can always state in this answer that you put it here for future reference or that you think it might help others.` Neither of those things belong in an answer.  They're just noise.  An answer is there to answer the question, not explain why you're answering the question.